# How are Windows VK_ constants declared?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

For example VK_LEFT, VK_DELETE, VK_ESCAPE, VK_RETURN, etc. How and where are they declared? Are they constants, #defines, or something else? Where do they come from?

If possible, please provide a file name/path where they are declared. Or some other info as specific as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are declared using `#define` in the file `winuser.h` in the Platform SDK. In my installation of Visual Studio 2008, the full path is

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include\WinUser.h
```

Answer (score 3):

There are also online copies of winuser.h , very handy sometimes :

http://www.woodmann.com/fravia/sources/WINUSER.H
http://doc.ddart.net/msdn/header/include/winuser.h.html

A bit of googling will get you more of those.

Answer (score 2):

To find how something is declared, install Visual Assist, put the cursor over the identifier in you code and press Alt+G
Or, right click over the identifier and choose "Go To Definition"
Or press F12

Answer (score 0):

These are macro-defined constants, [declared in winuser.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646271(VS.85).aspx).  To find where something is declared or defined you can read its documentation (Microsoft includes a section at the end, in Unix man pages it appears in the beginning), or go to the directory where the headers are and grep for the thing you're looking for.